# Embedding/delayed vector in simulink

Tags: delay, simulink

I would like to build an embedding vector, for each time step, in simulink, *ie*

```
\left[  y(t);y(t-\tau);y(t-2\tau);...;y(t-d\tau) \right ]
```

where `\tau` and `d` are fixed values and `y(t)` changed at each time step.

I tried to use [for iterator and delayed block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKR01.png) but i got a bug at the execution...
Do you have an idea how to build this at each time step?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [Tapped Delay](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/tappeddelay.html) block.

Comment: That was the block i was looking for! Thanks a lot :)